# How to Downgrade From iOS 11 Beta to iOS 11 Without Factory Resetting

Tags: ios

My iPhone is really starting to act up on the iOS 11 beta and I was wondering if there is anyway to downgrade from the iOS 11 beta to the regular version of iOS 11 without having to factory reset my iPhone.

Comment: What will you do in one to two weeks when the final iOS 11.1 probably will be released - then you’ll have the current beta version (I don’t expect any new large bugs fixing before the final release) - beta build number does already have a build number with final pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I did this but if I remember correctly, go to beta.apple.com on your phone and login. Go to the IOS section and un-enroll your device from the beta program. It should then allow you to download the non beta updated version of IOS 11.

It is likely the same build that you are running now. I am not sure if beta builds have extra debugging code in them or not. If this does not fix it you may need to back up the phone, erase it and restore from backup.

Comment: Doesn't work from the Apple website, however it works from Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it! Here's the steps in case anyone else needs help with this.

Head into Settings > General > Profile > Tap on your profile and then tap on Remove profile.

Now Restart your phone and navigate to the Software Update section and you will be able to download the regular version of iOS 11.